# How to use "disabledReason" in Android Management API?

Tags: java, android, android-management-api

So, I'm being able to disable the device using the AMAPI(Android Management API), but I want to let the user know why his device is being disabled, so I started looking for a way to show why the device was disabled and I found the "[disabledReason](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices)" property, but it's not working, or I don't know where is displaying the reason that I set.
If you know where is displaying or how to display the disabledReason I will be very thankful.

```
device.setState("DISABLED");
UserFacingMessage reason = new UserFacingMessage();
reason.setDefaultMessage("Reason why your device was disabled...");
device.setDisabledReason(reason);
androidManagementClient
        .enterprises()
        .devices()
        .patch(device.getName(), device).execute();
```

Comment: Using [`getDisabledReason()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidmanagement/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidmanagement/v1/model/Device.html#getDisabledReason--) you are able to see the message you set

Comment: But is there a way to show this message only using the AMAPI on the server side? I don't want to create an app on the client side and consume the AMAPI @Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue when using the `disabledReason` field in AMAPI. There is no message displayed on the device indicating why the device is disabled, and this issue has not yet been resolved, but you can see it on your JSON response if you set a customized `disabledReason.defaultMessage`.